# Image Button is black? picture not showing

Tags: xml, android-layout, android-studio

I'm trying to make an `ImageButton` in android studio but when i run it on my android nexus 6 phone, the picture is there but a different shade of black than the background.

Code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.bassammetwally.gymmasr.MainActivity"
    android:background="#080808">
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="175dp"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:background="@drawable/asd"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: put your drawable here

Comment: send us the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Its showing me perfectly correct. Its better to provide us some screenshot.